# Image resized when page displayed inside of jQuery Dialog and iFrame

Tags: asp.net, jquery, iframe, jquery-ui-dialog

I am having weird display issues using the jQuery dialog with an iframe in Firefox and IE8.

I have tested the page itself outside of the iframe and the problems are not reproduced, only when inside of the jQuery dialog.

**Issue**

[image]

*image actual size: 300x225 image display size: 400x300*

**JS Code - Parent Page**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var img = $('.photoLink');
    var imgSrc = img.attr('src');
    $('.photoLink').photoDialog({
        id: imageID,
        onClose: function() {
            img.attr('src', imgSrc + '&rand=' + (new Date()).getTime());
        }
    });
});

$.fn.photoDialog = function(options) {

    var defaults = {
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Photo Tool',
        minHeight: 560,
        minWidth: 540
        onClose: function(){}
    };
    var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        that =$(this);
        var $dialog = $('<div>')
            .html('<iframe src="' + opts.url + '?sn=' + opts.id + '" width="' + (opts.minWidth - 20) + '" height="' + (opts.minHeight - 20) + '" style="border: none;" scrolling="no"></iframe>')
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: opts.autoOpen,
                title: opts.title,
                minHeight: opts.minHeight,
                minWidth: opts.minWidth,
                modal: true,
                close: function() {
                    opts.onClose.call(that);
                }
            });

        $this.click(function() {
            $dialog.dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
    });
};
```

**Body Code - Child Page**

```
<div id="photo_holder" runat="server">
    <asp:Image ID="image_photo" style="display: none;" runat="server" />
</div>
```

**Style Code - Child Page**

```
#photo_holder { 
    position: relative; 
    float: left; 
    padding: 10px; 
    width: 300px; 
    height: 300px; 
}
.portrait { height: inherit; width: auto; }
.landscape { height: auto; width: inherit; }
```

**JS Code - Child Page**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#image_photo').load(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        if ($this.width() > $this.height()) {
            $this.attr('class', 'landscape');
        }
        else {
            $this.attr('class', 'portrait');
        }

    }).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

The class of the image is set dynamically based on image dimensions.

The image path is set in the code behind, no styling or resizing done.

The images are resized upon upload to be no larger than 300x300.

Display is correct in Chrome and Safari, but in IE and FF for some reason it enlarges the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing the following from the child page:

**CSS**

```
.portrait { height: inherit; width: auto; }
.landscape { height: auto; width: inherit; }
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#image_photo').load(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        if ($this.width() > $this.height()) {
            $this.attr('class', 'landscape');
        }
        else {
            $this.attr('class', 'portrait');
        }

    }).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

This corrected the issue in all browsers. Originally I had larger images and was trying to dynamically resize them via the jQuery/CSS. After writing server side code to resize the images upon upload I no longer needed this process but hadn't removed it from the original code.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the image styles width to 100%

Comment: I cannot change the sizing of the photo as it will be cropped and I need the correct X,Y coordinates of the crop based on the actual images size. The CSS for landscape and portrait exist to dynamically align the photo based on the dimensions. Also that styling information is in the child page, which renders fine on its own. The issue is when launched in an iframe using the jQuery dialog.